# Dynamically change style attributes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading percentages from a database, then use that number to create a bar showing visual progress. I need to do something like this on my aspx page:

```
       <%  
       if (ViewData["width"] != null){
        <div style="width: <%: ViewData["width"] %>px;"
       </div>
       }%>
```

Of course the above method doesn't work, but hopefully you can see what im trying to achieve. How do i change style attributes dynamically in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just wrote HTML in the middle of a code block. You need to put your HTML outside the code block.

```
<% if (ViewData["width"] != null) { %>
    <div style="width: <%: ViewData["width"] %>px;"></div>
<% } %>
```

Alternatively, you could switch to the Razor language which does away with all the `<% %>`s and allows you to intersperse C# and HTML much easier. It looks like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.width != null) {
    <div style="width: @(ViewBag.width)px;"></div>
}
```

Comment: This is MVC2 so I cant use ViewBag. Also, this will be a result set with numerous results, so i need the HTML inside the code block as i'll be looping through a for statement. Unless i'm misunderstanding what you're saying

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: The HTML will still be inside the if statement (and any other control structures). Just outside the part that's interpreted as C#. Try it!

Comment: You know what, my method did work. I never tested it. My code didnt change color and it looked like a comment.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: I'm finding that a bit hard to believe as it has a syntax error. You sure you didn't miscopypaste it to SO?

Comment: I only posted a snippet of my code. No reason to bog everyone down with a bunch of irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should work, you just need to put the `div` code outside of the server block.

```
<% if (ViewData["width"] != null){ %>
    <div style="width: <%: ViewData["width"] %>px;"
    </div>
<% } %>
```